# Overlapping titles with R plot command?

Tags: r, plot, graph

Currently, I am having trouble using R studio when I try to graph things.
I want to have the Y axis only say: E(sigma) of iteration and the X axis to only say: List size. Unfortunately it is overlapping and one cannot read it. Is there a way to fix this. I apologize for my ignorance, but I am self-teaching myself R in order to avoid using Excel, so I really am a novice. Thanks for all the help. Here is the R code:

```
  N = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000)
  Shell Sort = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 )
  M = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 )
  plot(N, M, type = "o", col = "green");par(new=TRUE)
  plot(N, Shell Sort, type = "o", col = "blue")
  legend('topleft', col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1, 
         legend = c("N", "Shell Sort"), bty='n', cex=.59)
  title(main="Comparisons - Speed", col.main="black", font.main=4)
  title(xlab="List size", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
  title(ylab="∑ of iterations", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
```

From what I read from your comment I did this:

```
        N = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000)
        InsertionSort = c(33, 80, 127, 177, 245, 318, 420, 532, 654, 815 )
        ShellSort = c(18, 48, 111, 156, 213, 283, 360, 451, 566, 684 )
        plot(N, InsertionSort, type = "o", col = "green", 
             xlab="List size", ylab="∑ of iterations", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0),
             main="Comparisons - Speed", col.main="black", font.main=4)
        par(new=TRUE)
        plot(N, ShellSort, type = "o", col = "blue", 
             xlab="", ylab="")

        legend('topleft', col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1, 
               legend = c("N", "Shell Sort"), bty='n', cex=.9)
```

and now the y values are being overlapped. i apologize for not explaining myself clearly the first time. thanks for the help.

Here is the picture 
[image: Graph]

Comment: By using `par(new=TRUE)` and then running `plot` a second time, you are superimposing a whole new plot with new axes and new axis tick labels that (in general) will be scaled differently than your first plot, hence the overlap. Instead, don't run `par(new=TRUE)` and use the `lines` function instead of the `plot` function to add new data lines to the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an `RStudio` issue. The `plot` function by default adds x and y axis titles to your plot based on the names of the x and y variables in the plot. You can get rid of those by changing them to the empty string and then add them later as you've done. Or, you can just add them directly in the plot command. I've made a few changes to your code, based on what I'm guessing you're trying to do. Let me know if I've guessed wrong:

```
N = seq(100,1000,100)
ShellSort = seq(100,1000,100)
M = seq(50,950,100)

plot(N, M, type = "o", col = "green", xlab="", ylab="")
#par(new=TRUE)
lines(N, ShellSort, type = "o", col = "blue")

legend('topleft', col = c("black", "red"), lty = 1, 
       legend = c("N", "Shell Sort"), bty='n', cex=.59)

title(main="Comparisons - Speed", col.main="black", font.main=4)
title(xlab="List size", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
title(ylab="∑ of iterations", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
```

The code below adds the main and x- and y-axis titles directly in the plot command. Then you run the same code as above, but skip the three calls to `title`.

```
plot(N, M, type = "o", col = "green", 
     xlab="List size", ylab="∑ of iterations", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0),
     main="Comparisons - Speed", col.main="black", font.main=4)
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: somewhat, but I actually wanted two different lines with different Y values. I'm unsure if i followed your advice correctly, but I'll post what I understood

Comment: So, after you've plotted the first set of x and y values with `plot`, use the `lines` function to add additional lines (as in my example code). (And if you want just points, use the `points` function.)

Comment: sorry for not replying, but this did help.